# How to write this nested IF function in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I am trying to write the following function in Excel.

if P2 is greater than or equal to 3 and AD2 is 0
OR
if P2 is greater than or equal to 2 and AD2 is greater than or equal to 1
OR 
if P2 is greater than or equal to 1 and AD2 is 2

Then do the following:
(H2+V2)/(P2+AD2),-999)

I have had a go at writing the following to no avail.

=IF(AND(P2>=3,AD2>=0),OR(AND(P2>=2,AD2>=1)),OR(AND(P2>=1,AD2>=2)),(H2+V2)/(P2+AD2),-999)

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated as I am a novice at Excel functions.

Many thanks,

Ash

Answer (score 1):

Erm...

I think this is right:

```
=IF(OR(AND(P2>=3,AD2=0),AND(P2>=2,AD2>=1),AND(P2>=1,AD2=2)),(H2+V2)/(P2+AD2),-999)
```

You need to nest your different `AND` conditions within a `OR` function...

---

Easiest way to do it, is to have your seperate functions in a cell each and build it up a step at a time, until you're sure it's right.. Then you can paste the function into one cell if required.

Say the below are in Cells `A1`, `A2`, `A3`

```
=AND(P2>=3,AD2=0)
=AND(P2>=2,AD2>=1)
=AND(P2>=1,AD2=2)
```

Then your total formula in a cell:

```
=IF(OR(A1,A2,A3),(H2+V2)/(P2+AD2),-999)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
=IF(OR(
       AND(P2>=3,AD2>=0),
       AND(P2>=2,AD2>=1),
       AND(P2>=1,AD2>=2)
      ),
    (H2+V2)/(P2+AD2),-999)
```

it's slightly unclear from your question what'd be the correct

- `AND(P2>=3,AD2>=0)` and `AND(P2>=1,AD2>=2)`
  or
- `AND(P2>=3,AD2=0)` and `AND(P2>=1,AD2=2)`

but you can easily modify this behaviour in the formula above.